# Import gradle class in another gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I have a gradle class called CustomReport in my *custom.gradle* file. I want to import the CustomReport class and use it in *jacoco.gradle* file. How can I achieve that? The files are at the same level in the fileTree.

Comment: groovy import works in the same way as java, except you can put non-compiled groovy file to your classpath.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach to share code between build scripts is to leverage Gradle's `buildSrc` folder.

It effectively allows to place code on the classpath of all build scripts of a project.

Have a look at [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources) for more details, including how to set it up for Groovy code.